# Sci Fi short story collection, including a story about a planet where the currency is art and another about siblings fighting the Devil's influence

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

I have  been looking for years for a specific short story collection/anthology (not sure which). I am not 100% certain they are all in the same book, but I think they are.

Details are a story about a planet(?) where the currency is art and an artist tries to murder the protagonist, who cannot escape the planet because his art is not worth enough(?), and is aided in escape from the artist by a cyborg/android(?) woman. A plot point is that her sweat can dissolve dead tissue, in this case leather.

Another story deals with siblings (brother and sister) fighting the influence of the Devil in the desert. The story ends with the brother firing a submachine gun(?) in the desert and him rejecting the Devil's(?) influence.

Another story dealt with a woman mathematician being abducted into a medieval(?) society, where she escapes captivity after a prince(?) comes to her and taunts that to break the lock on her restraints she would need to solve a complex mathematical problem. She does, and is brought to another area by another prince(?), that is apparently rife with mathematical knowledge in the architecture.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this collection?

Comment: Roughly 2015-2018, my high-school years, I read it in the library. But since it was in the library, that probably won't help much.

If it helps, I am somewhat certain that it had a campfire on the cover, but I would prefer if you don't quote me on that.

Comment: Do you remember if all the stories were by the same author?

Comment: Sorry, I do not, your guess on whether it is an anthology or a collection are as good as mine in this case.